# When I using Enum in laravel gives me error during package installation and composer commands

Tags: php, laravel, enums, composer-php

When i use Enum in laravel it gives me error during package installation and composer commands:
Generating optimized autoload files

***Class App\Enums\Gender:string located in MyProject\app\Enums\Gender.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.***

I Want to use php(8.1) feature Enum in laravel(9)

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Is this a PHP problem, a Laravel problem, or a Composer problem?

Comment: @NicoHaase 
When I use enum in Controller and Views it works  but when I installed sompackages the errors occurs during composer package installations.
So I tried to add a space after semicolon in enums  the problem solved.
" enum enumName: string{ } " so the problem solved.

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be space between "Gender:" and "string".
I change this:

```
enum Gender:string { 
    case Male = 'male';
    case Female = 'female';
}
```

to this:

```
enum Gender: string { 
    case Male = 'male';
    case Female = 'female';
}
```

The problem Solved.